# Use math symbol from different font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols, newtxmath

I'd like to produce a "⋆" operator symbol with rather narrow points, resembling an asterisk, as seen in the Wikipedia page on cross-correlation:

[image: f \star g]

If I use the default math font (Latin Modern Math), the command `\star` produces exactly what I'm looking for (and seems to be what this Wikipedia page is using). But I'd much prefer to continue using the `newtxmath` package, which in this case produces something more resembling a regular pentagram, similar to the one seen in Wolfram Mathworld:

[image: f \star g]

Is there a way to have the `\star` command write a character in the default math font while using the `newtxmath` package elsewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the modern toolchain, with `unicode-math`, you can load a symbol from another math font with the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[range=\star]
```

Comment: What is the `\defaultfontfeatures` line doing here? Can I use this with only the first and last lines?

Comment: @Jackson That automatically scales all fonts in the document to the same x-height.  `Scale=MatchUppercase` would scale them to the same caps-height.

Comment: @Jackson You could remove the `\defaultfontfeatures` line and it would still work. You could also remove `\setmainfont` to use the default main font, Latin Modern Roman. You do need to set a math font before you can replace individual symbols with `range=`. So you need at least the first line and the last two.

Comment: @Davislor Look, I have not seen your answer :-(.

Comment: Can you specify what "modern toolchain" means ? Is that valid for pdflatex ?

Comment: @VincentFourmond No, I meant the toolchain with `unicode-math` and LuaLaTeX (or XeLaTeX, although that is now in maintenance mode as well). It does not support PDFLaTeX.

Answer (score 9):

You could borrow the `\star` from Latin Modern.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\DeclareSymbolFont{LMletters}{OML}{lmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lmstar}{\mathbin}{LMletters}{63}
\begin{document}
\( f \star g \)

\( f \lmstar g \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Can you tell me a little about how the syntax works? Is the ```\DeclareSymbolFont``` line defining a command ```LMletters```, and the number ```63``` choosing the star symbol? And if so, what is OML, and where can I find a list of symbols with their corresponding numbers?

Answer (score 7):

### `Update 1: after the correct comment of @Vincent`

After many attemps and looked the manual of [`MnSymbol`](http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/fonts/mnsymbol/MnSymbol.pdf) I have taken all the fonts of type `MnSymbolC`

[image]

[image]

etc...and with **\DeclareMathSymbol{`\thinstar`}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{`134`}** I have obtained only the `\thinstar` operator (code 134).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolC}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
<-6> MnSymbolC5
<6-7> MnSymbolC6
<7-8> MnSymbolC7
<8-9> MnSymbolC8
<9-10> MnSymbolC9
<10-12> MnSymbolC10
<12-> MnSymbolC12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{b}{n}{
<-6> MnSymbolC-Bold5
<6-7> MnSymbolC-Bold6
<7-8> MnSymbolC-Bold7
<8-9> MnSymbolC-Bold8
<9-10> MnSymbolC-Bold9
<10-12> MnSymbolC-Bold10
<12-> MnSymbolC-Bold12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC}         {U}  {MnSymbolC}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{MnSyC} {bold}{U} {MnSymbolC}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\thinstar}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{134}


\begin{document}
$\sum_{i=1}^n g\thinstar f \cup R$
or other
\[\sum \sigma_s\prod a_i\]
\end{document}
```

It seem that the symbols are all of `newtxmath`

[image]

if we compare with `\sum` and `\prod` of MnSymbol (for example),

[image]

---

I add some proposals....

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{newtxtext}
    \usepackage{newtxmath}
    \usepackage{MnSymbol}
    \usepackage{wasysym}
    
    
    \begin{document}
    \( f \star g \), \verb|classic star|
    
    \( f \mathbin{\filledstar}  g \), \verb|MnSymbol package|
    
    $f \mathrel{\thinstar} g $, \verb|MnSymbol package|
    
    $f \mathbin{\APLstar} g $, \verb|Table 330: wasysym APL Symbols|
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One should know that loading ``MnSymbol`` this way will change many symbols in the font. In fact, if I'm not mistaken, the ``\star`` symbol displayed in this example comes from ``MnSymbol`` and not from ``newtx`` or computer modern.

Comment: Is there a way to use the ```\thinstar``` symbol without also having the```\star``` symbol be the one in ```MnSymbol```?

Comment: @Vincent It is absolutely true..and I now, after many attemps, my answer. +1 for your comment.

Comment: @Jackson I have improved my answer....Now, I think, :-) you can use only `\thinstar` from `MnSymbol` if I have not make of the mistakes.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for this thorough answer