# How to use a single math symbol, in medium and bold, from Latin Modern?

Tags: fonts, symbols

I use `newtx` and `newtxmath` in pdflatex with TeXLive, but I would like to use the `\mathcal{O}` symbol from Latin Modern. Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557679/192504), I am able to access the medium-series version. In the preamble, I add

```
 \DeclareSymbolFont{LMletters}{OMS}{lmsy}{m}{n}
 \DeclareMathSymbol{\lmO}{\mathbin}{LMletters}{79}
```

And then in the document, I can use e.g. `$\lmO (N^{2})$`.

But I would also like to use the boldface version of that symbol. Preferably it should work automatically with `\bm`, but if that is too hard, I wouldn't mind having simply a macro for it, e.g. `\lmBO`. However, the following attempt

```
  \DeclareSymbolFont{LMBletters}{OMS}{lmbsy}{b}{n}
```

returns the warning

```
   LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/lmbsy/b/n' undefined
   (Font)              using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead on input line 30.
```

Note that `\fonttable{lmbsy10}` does print out, on my system, all the expected symbols, including the boldfaced mathcal O.

How do I access the boldfaced mathcal O from Latin Modern (while using`newtxmath` for all other math)? If possible, how to make this Latim Modern mathcal O work with `\bm`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\SetSymbolFont` to declare the font for math version `bold`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{LMletters}{OMS}{lmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{LMletters}{bold}{OMS}{lmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mscrO}{\mathalpha}{LMletters}{79}

\begin{document}
\[ O \quad \mathcal{O} \quad \mscrO \quad \boldsymbol{\mscrO}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern + NewTx sample]

You might also declare `\newcommand\mbfscrO{\boldsymbol{\mscrO}}` for convenience and compatibility.  I’m not sure whether giving this symbol the spacing of a binary operator was intentional, but if it was, you can easily change it back.  You can optionally `\usepackage{bm}` after all your other math commands.

In `unicode-math`, you can override this symbol for both `\mathcal` and `\mathbfcal` with the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`, so:

```
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[Scale=MatchUppercase,
                                range={\mscrO,\mbfscrO}]
```

You can then use `\mbfscrO`, `\mathbfcal{O}`, and a few other synonyms.

Comment: And I see @egreg posted this as a comment while I was writing my MWE.

Comment: That worked, including with `\bm`. Thanks!